# Properly testing for a function that logs an error message and raises SystemExit if condition not met

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

## Background

I would like to test for the following behaviours of a function:

1. If condition is met function raises `None`
2. If condition is not met function:

   - Outputs log message of `ERROR` level
   - Raises `SystemExit`

## Example

The following trivial function checks if directory is accessible. The logging configuration `logging.getLogger('__main__.' + __name__)` is defined in `__main__.py` as the function is part of a package.

```
###########
# Modules #
###########
import os


###########
# Logging #
###########
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('__main__.' + __name__)


#############
# Functions #
#############

def check_directory_access(folder_path):
    """Test if directory is readable"""
    if os.access(folder_path, os.R_OK) is not True:
        logger.error("Provided folder %s is invalid", folder_path)
        raise SystemExit
```

## Testing

```
 #########
 # Tests #
 #########

 class TestDirectoryChecking(unittest.TestCase):
     """Unit test checking utility functions"""

     def test_return_none_correct_path(self):
         """Test if function checking for valid directory works"""
         # Should return None
         self.assertIsNone(utilities.check_directory_access(folder_path="/"))

     def test_raise_exception_wrong_path(self):
         """Raises sception for wrong path"""
         # Should raise a system exception
         with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
             utilities.check_directory_access(folder_path="/wrong_path")

     def test_outputting_log_message(self):
         """Function returns log message in case of wrong directory"""
         with self.assertLogs(level='ERROR'):
             utilities.check_directory_access(folder_path="/wrong_path")


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

### Problem

The last test errors:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_outputting_log_message (test_utility_functions.TestDirectoryChecking)
Function returns log message in case of wrong directory
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/module_path/tests/test_utility_functions.py", line 38, in test_outputting_log_message
    utilities.check_directory_access(folder_path="/wrong_path")
  File "/module_path/sample_module/utilities.py", line 30, in check_directory_access
    raise SystemExit
SystemExit

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your error is actually on `test_outputting_log_message`, which you're not adding the `with self.assertRaises` context. Since `/wrong_path` doesn't exist, the exception is raised just like in the previous test, but this time it's not expected in the test, so it breaks.

---

*Working solution*

```
 def test_outputting_log_message(self):
     """Function returns log message in case of wrong directory"""
     with self.assertRaises(SystemExit), self.assertLogs(level='ERROR') as log:
         utilities.check_directory_access(folder_path="/wrong_path")
     self.assertRegex(str(log), '.*Provided folder /wrong_path is invalid')
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I've added this: `with self.assertLogs(level='ERROR'): #\n with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):` Is this the way you would do it? I come from R background and I'm used to working with [`testthat`](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat).

Comment: @Konrad It's been a while since I've had to work with multiple context managers (the `with` blocks), but if I'm not mistaken, you can also do it like `with self.assertLogs(level='ERROR'), self.assertRaises(SystemExit):`, all in one line.

Comment: So I've provided: `with self.assertRaises(SystemExit), self.assertLogs(level='INFO'):                                                                                                                              utilities.check_directory_access(folder_path="/wrong_path")` The problem is that tests pass; however, the tests should fail as I'm not expecting **INFO** but **ERROR** log. My guess is that the tests are not testing properly then.

Comment: Or is it checking for "Error and higher"?

Comment: @Konrad Yes, I believe it checks for 'INFO or higher', according to the docs: _A context manager to test that at least one message is logged on the logger or one of its children, with at least the given level._. One thing that you could do is `with self.assertRaises(SystemExit), self.assertLogs(level='INFO') as log:` and then check for the `log` object's properties, like in the example here in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll *test* this :)

Comment: You had a good idea. I'm using the following check `self.assertRegex(str(log), '.*Provided folder /wrong_path is invalid')`

Comment: @Konrad Awesome, glad that you arrived into a solution! I see you've added it to my answer, but I'm curious: shouldn't the last line be a bit more indented, to stay under the `with` block, so it has access to the `log` variable?